# What functions must I implement to make a class iterable?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

I am writing a class that contains a collection of child objects of the same class and would like to iterate, and index, through them using the standard-provided functions instead of functions like: `first()`, `next()`, `previous()`, `last()`, `getchild(x)` etc.

In c++14, which functions must I implement to make a class iterable/indexable in all cases?

The functions:

- `begin()`
- `cbegin()`
- `rbegin()`
- `crbegin()`
- `end()`
- `cend()`
- `rend()`
- `crend()`

come to mind, although, probably not necessarily *all* of them need be implemented. Also optionally (for programmer convenience):

- `size()`
- `empty()`

Are there any other functions that I must implement, like the pre-increment/decrement or post-increment/decrement and array subscript operators, or is it really just `begin()` and `end()` and their variants?

Comment: Overloaded operators of `++,--, +,-`

Comment: I don't think there is an "iterable" concept, so it is pretty much up to you. There is a [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept, and a few iterator ones too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your container implements `begin()` and `end()` as member functions, and the return type of the functions supports the pre-increment operator, you can use it in most contexts. The important ones that I can think of are:

1. `range-for`. You can use:

   ```
   Container c;
   for ( auto& item : c ) { ... }
   ```
2. Functions that work with iterators. Example:

   ```
   Container c;
   Item item;
   std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), item);
   ```

Making the iterator a sub-class of [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is best way to ensure that it will be compatible with all the standard algorithms. (Thanks @Adrian).

Comment: "and the return type of the functions supports the pre-increment operator"

Iterator should also have defined typedefs such as `value_type` etc, otherwise using them with standard containers may not compile. The best way to do that would be to subclass `std::iterator`.

Comment: Apparently `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17.

Comment: @Spidey, thanks for pointing that out. Do you know whether there is something else that has replaced `std::iterator` in C++17?

Comment: @RSahu I'm in the process of trying to find a proper solution :)

Comment: @RSahu According to https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/05/08/std-iterator-deprecated/ `std::iterator` is just a struct defining 5 basic types that the iterator should provide. These 5 basic types aren't complicated and `std::iterator` can be replaced with 5 typedefs/using aliases. As far as I can tell the rest stays the same.